# get limited records in eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

First , i'm sorry for my english.

I have two tables: `Users`

```
class Users extends Model {
    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\posts','user_id');
    }
}
```

and `posts`

```
class posts extends Model{
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Users','user_id');
    }
}
```

Each users has many posts.

I want take only 4 posts of each users.

I tested this code, but it does not work.

```
Users::with(['posts'=>function($query){
    return $query->skip(0)->take(4);
}])->get();
```

Comment: What error is returning? Please share.

Comment: Not any error . This get 4 posts of first user and then not get any posts of another users

Comment: Does the other users have posts? lol

Comment: THINK I got it...man, learned something new here. Check updated answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't limit results on eager loads**

*However, you can run it like this:*

```
return Users::with('posts')->get()->map(function ($users) {
    $users->posts = $users->setRelation('posts', $users->posts->take(4));
    return $users;
});
```

Comment: i try it and it take only 4 users with all posts of each 4 users

Comment: thanks , i also try this . this take 4 posts of first user and then not take any posts

Comment: Yes. This is true.Thanks, my friend